# How to delay api calls in fb api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am making 2 requests using for loop simultaneously when someone clicks on a button. Then I post a message to their profile; say the messages are the following :

```
var my_array=["Hi i am jason", "I am feeling great today"];
```

Above is the array and then I update the statuses using the for loop, so first it loops through the first message and then through the second message.

As I am making this request, those 2 messages are updated on their profile at the same time(maybe a delay of some ms). What I want is the delay of 2s between those 2 messages(indirectly I want the delay between the for loop indices).

So when I click on the button the first message should be updated right away and the second one after 2s.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: important side question: where does the message come from? does the user enter both messages?

Comment: no the user doesn't add the message , i have some ready-made messages that i want to be updated

Comment: ok, then please read the last part of my answer, i will include the link to the platform policy too. prefilling is not allowed, that´s a very important rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a delay in JavaScript with setTimeout: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

For example:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    //do your second API call
}, 2000); //2 seconds delay
```

One way to solve this (untested, but you should get the idea):

```
var currentMessageId = 0;

function doAPICall() {
    //do API call with my_array[currentMessageId]

    currentMessageId++;
    if (currentMessageId < my_array.length) {
        window.setTimeout(doAPICall, 2000); //2 seconds delay
    } else {
        //done
    }
}
```

You can also encapsulate the whole code in a function, so you can call it on button click. Or just set the currentMessageId parameter to zero in the `else` block.

Btw, prefilling the message is not allowed according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). The user must write every single message by himself.

Comment: Actually when i submit a form then i make api call for publishing those 2 messages... i used the setTimeout function and what i got is.. it doesn't even make api calls and it redirects to the page where the form is going to be submitted. For example, i have actions="profile.php", it already redirects to profile.php and doesn't even make api calls now.

Comment: well, don´t submit a form then ;)

Comment: No the form has to be submitted! It is must ! Please help me out and figure something out how to tackle this...how to make form submit later ..unless the for loop meets its end.

Comment: then just submit the form after you do the message sending. i am not sure what the problem is, there are so many possibilities. there is the "//done" comment in my code, just submit it there with javascript.

Comment: "how to submit a form with javascript" would be a different question though, one that has been answered a lot on stackoverflow already - if that is the problem.

Comment: Apparently, when i set the setTimeout function in my code , the api call is also not working. I am trying to schedule a post..when i include that function the post gets delayed..and everything seems to be working fine but when i check the page , there is no post scheduled.

Comment: you need to start debugging then. you usually get a response from the api calls, debug the response.